# C# - Fuzzy compare of two large string arrays

Tags: c#, string, linq, loops, compare

I need to find all strings in B that "partly" exists in A.

```
B = [ "Hello World!", "Hello Stack Overflow!", "Foo Bar!", "Food is nice...", "Hej" ]
A = [ "World", "Foo" ]
C = B.FuzzyCompare(A) // C = [ "Hello World!", "Foo Bar!", "Food is nice..." ]
```

I've been looking into using [`Levenshtein Distance Algorithm`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) for the "fuzzy" part of the problem, as well as [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) for the iterations.
However, A * B usually results in over 1,5 billion comparisons.

How should i go about this? Is there a way to quickly *"almost compare"* two Lists of strings?

Comment: You examples don't seem to lend themselves to Levenshtein Distance.  They look more like checking for substrings.

Comment: @juharr yep, this is an ideal problem for a Suffix Trie, per my answer below.

Comment: How many elements are usually in `B` and `A`?  And how large are the elements, on average, in `B`, e.g. "Hello World!" == 12? Also, are the elements in `A` just single words?

Comment: @JarrodDixon on average the elements in A and B are between 100 and 200 characters.

Comment: @Olian04 thanks! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's sufficient to simply compare substrings, this would be much more efficient:

```
var C = B.Where(s1 => A.Any(s2 => s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: Providing he wants to ignore case?

Comment: @Liam: i think case doesn't matter if he even wants to find similar strings. If it does he can simply change it to a different `StringComparison`. If i would have shown `String.Contains` he would not have known how to compare case insensitively.

Comment: @Rango can you have a look at similar kind of problem I have but I am actually passing threshold value for similarity  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511595/optimize-matching-elements-from-two-large-data-sets-using-levenshtein-distance/54516063?noredirect=1#comment95866563_54516063

Comment: @Rango Can we somehow specify a percentage of similarity in this query? Like only select the words from List B which are 70% or more similar to the word in List A? Thanks

Comment: @Rango Thank you very much, I tried using the Levenshtein distance approach. But the problem I face is of quadratic scaling, This is what I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511595/optimize-matching-elements-from-two-large-data-sets-using-levenshtein-distance Can you suggest how I can optimize this?

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a good use of a [Suffix Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

A Suffix Trie is a tree with no payload. It indexes all suffixes of a given string or sentence so that they can be searched in O(n) time. So, if your input in `A` was "hello", it would index "hello", "ello", "llo", "lo", and "o" in a way that would allow any of those substrings to immediately and efficiently be looked up without any additional enumeration of the set of `A`.

Basically, take all the values in `A` and process them into a Suffix Trie which is an `O(n * m)` operation done once where `n` is the number of elements in `A` and `m` is the length of the elements. Then for each element of `B` check for it in the Suffix Trie which is also an `O(n * m)` operation where `n` is the number of elements in `B` and `m` is the length of the elements.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this as it sounds ace but I just don't understand it... :)

Comment: @Liam basically the original question specifically asks to avoid the A * B cost of 1.5 billion comparisons, which this answer does, but the others I see here do not.

Comment: You might be able to help me out here, I wanted to update my answer in relation to yours but I wans't sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332900/what-woukd-the-big-o-be-of-a-for-loop-with-an-any-inside-it

Comment: @Haney can you help me out here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212823/the-process-to-calculate-the-levenshtien-distance-of-each-element-of-a-large-dat

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be other thinking it:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string test in B)
{
   if (A.Any(a => test.Contains(a))
      results.Add(test);
}
```

BTW the [complexity of this is somewhere in the region of `O(n)`(best) and `O(n*m)`(worst)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332900/what-would-the-big-o-be-of-a-nested-for-loop-with-an-any-inside-it) (where `n` is the numer of results in `A` and `m` is the number of results in `B`)