# What would the Big O be of a nested for loop with an Any() inside it?

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o

This questions is basically a follow-on from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332524/542251). I really wanted to say what the Big-O of this algorithm would be, but I wasn't sure my claim was completely sound.

So given two arrays:

```
B = [ "Hello World!", "Hello Stack Overflow!", "Foo Bar!", "Food is nice...", "Hej" ]
A = [ "World", "Foo" ]
```

what is the Big O of:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string test in B)
{
   if (A.Any(a => test.Contains(a))
      results.Add(test);
}
```

I believe it to be somewhere between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` as it depends where in the result the `Any()` matches...

Comment: that's what I *believe* it to be, but I'm really not 100%.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still considered an O(n^2) algorithm even if it can break early.

Comment: I guess the question here is what is `n` in this case, the number of items in `A` or in `B`? If it is just one of those 2 the complexity would be `O(n)`

Comment: @heijp06 It's both of them since the algorithm iterates over both. Hence O(n^2)

Comment: @itsme86 Wouldn't that only be the case if the number of items in `A` depended linearly on the number of items in `B` (or vice versa)?

Comment: @heijp06 Big-O notation doesn't take into consideration individual data sets. It's a high level efficiency evaluation of an algorithm. Nested iterations without optimizations (e.g. binary search) are O(n^2).

Comment: Since the input is constant, so is the algorithmic complexity

Comment: It's not really related to the question, but I feel the need to point out that this could be written as `List<string> results = B.Where(b => A.Any(b.Contains)).ToList();`. Also if there's a chance the results might not be needed it's better to store an enumerable than to write the results to a list so you're not wasting time calculating results that are just going to be discarded.

Comment: @itsme86 The complexity here is `O(mn)` with `m` the length of `B` and `n` the length of `A`. it can only be `O(n^2)` if `m = cn` for sufficiently large `n`, with `c` some constant independent of `m` and `n`. We then have `m = cn` and `O(mn) = O(cn^2) = O(n^2)`. But there is nothing in the problem statement that indicates that that simplification can be made.

Comment: **Hint**: What's n? Your question is ill-defined. The time complexity of your algorithm depends on several variables: the lengths of the two arrays, the lengths of the strings in them. Defining the problem clearly will help you reason about it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let length of `A` be `N` and length of `B` be `M`. We have two extremal cases:

1. The *worst* one:

   ```
   a => test.Contains(a)
   ```

   returns `false` on every `a`, so `A.Any` has to scan the *entire* `A` and we have

   ```
   O(N * M)
   ```
2. The *best* one:

   ```
   a => test.Contains(a)
   ```

   returns `true` on the very 1st item of `A` and thus `A.Any` *returns immediately* and we have only

   ```
   O(M)
   ```

Actual complexity is somewhere in between (both borders included):

```
    [O(M)..O(M*N)]
```

Comment: To be clear: best case complexity is O(M), worst case complexity is O(M*N) and average case complexity is O(M*(N/2)) = O(M*N)

Comment: @Robin: When taking on *average case* we must know the *distribution* (i.e. average of what); the question doesn't provide any hint of it. You've solved the case when each item of `A` is somewhere in `B` (all items of `B` are distinct) and the distribution of `A` items in `B` is uniform

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: The runtime of `.Contains` is not trivial to the question.  It should be mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Echoing @AdamMartin here. You've treated `Contains()` as if it's always an O(n) operation and that is only its best case. OP had the answer right to begin with.

Answer (score 11):

It's close, however as others mention it's going to be `O(n*m)` as the sizes of each of your collections differ (with the best case being `O(n)` and worst being `O(n*m)`) otherwise, if you were iterating the same size collection twice, you'd get `O(n^2)`.

**Taking a Look Behind the Scenes at `Any()`**

You can take a look at [the source for the `Enumerable.Any()` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0) to dig into this a bit further. You'll see a `foreach` loop to iterate through until it finds a match for the predicate which reinforces your assumption of it being `O(n)`:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
   if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
   if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
   // Another loop to iterate through the collection until the predicate is matched
   foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

As you can see `Any()` by itself is going to be `O(n)` for it's length and nesting that inside of an existing loop `O(m)` should give you `O(n*m)` for the entire code. However, it's possible that it could be as low as `O(m)`.

Answer (score 5):

`.Any()` should be `O(n)` as it searches the container until it finds the first matching instance.  So that, in a foreach loop should be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you provide `A` and `B` just for example of their contents, and you are aware that complexity has meaning only for sets of inputs (like average, worst and best cases), not for individual inputs.

My point is, depending on the problem requirements and use case, you can make very different estimates for the code complexity.

Let `n` be `A.Length` and `m` be `B.Length`. Complexity of the given code then can be calculated in a few different ways:

1. Assume `string.Contains` is `O(1)`. In practice, such strong assumption can be made, for example, if we know for sure that no string is longer than some fixed in advance length. Then code complexity is of course **`O(n*m)`**.
2. Assume `string.Contains` is `O(x*y)`, where `x` and `y` are lengths of haystack and needle. Let the longest string in `A` be of length `k_A` and the longest string in `B` be of length `k_B`. Then code complexity would be **`O(n*m*k_A*k_B)`**

For the second case, there is another (more practical) approach:

Let `S_A` be the sum of lengths for all strings in `A`, and `S_B` be the sum of length for all strings in `B`. Then code complexity would be **`O(S_A * S_B)`**.

That's it for the worst case. For the average case, though, and for the most practical cases, `string.Contains` is `O(x + y)`. So average code complexity would be **`O(n*m*(k_A + k_B))`** or **`O((S_B + k_A) * n + (S_A + k_B) * m)`**.

Answer (score 0):

it's essentially a nested for loop, so the big O should be O(n^2) for worst case scenario