# Optimize matching elements from two large data sets using Levenshtein distance (comparing each element to each other element)

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I am currently working on a problem to find the best matches of data in a List namely "ListA" from another List called "ListB". Whenever I find a match of an element for "ListA" with any element in "ListB" which has a confidence and accuracy with 70% or greater I add the matched string from List B and the string in List A to a tuple which i further save in a database.

Levenshtien algorithm gives me a number which I compare with my threshold of 70 and if the values returned is equal or greater than the 70 percent threshold I append it with the original string element of "ListA".

The code that I have written for this process works fine if the records in "ListA" and "ListB" are within thousands of values and if I increase the records to a million it takes about an hour to calculate the distance for each element of the List A.

I need to optimize the process for huge data sets. Please advise where do I need to make the improvements.

My code for the process so far looks like this

```
  public static PerformFuzzyMatch()
  {
    // Fetch the ListA & List B from SQL tables
     var ListACount = await FuzzyMatchRepo.FetchListACount();
     var ListB = await FuzzyMatchRepo.FetchListBAsync();

    //Split the ListA data to smaller chunks and loop through those chunks 
     var splitGroupSize = 1000;
     var sourceDataBatchesCount = ListACount / splitGroupSize;

     // Loop through the smaller chunks of List A
     for (int b = 0; b < sourceDataBatchesCount; b++)
     {
       var currentBatchMatchedWords = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>();
       int skipRowCount = b * splitGroupSize;
       int takeRowCount = splitGroupSize;

       // Get chunks of data from ListA according to the skipRowCount and takeRowCount
   var currentSourceDataBatch = FuzzyMatchRepository.FetchSourceDataBatch(skipRowCount, takeRowCount);

 //Loop through the ListB and parallely calculate the distance between chunks of List A and List B data
   for (int i = 0; i < ListB.Count; i++)
   {
     Parallel.For(
      0,
      currentSourceDataBatch.Count,
      new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 },
      cntr =>
      {
         try
         {
            //call the Levenshtien Algorithm to calculate the distance between each element of ListB and the smaller chunk of List A.
              int leven = LevenshteinDistance(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr], ListB[i]);
              int length = Math.Max(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr].Length, ListB[i].Length);
              double similarity = double similarity = 1.0 - (double)leven / length;
              if ((similarity * 100) >= 70)
              {
     currentBatchMatchedWords.Add(Tuple.Create(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr], ListB[i], similarity));
            }
          cntr++;
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
        }
      });
     }
   }
  }
```

And the algorithm which it calls is to calculate  the distance is

```
public static int LevenshteinDistance(this string input, string comparedTo, bool caseSensitive = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comparedTo))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (!caseSensitive)
        {
            input = Common.Hashing.InvariantUpperCaseStringExtensions.ToUpperInvariant(input);
            comparedTo = Common.Hashing.InvariantUpperCaseStringExtensions.ToUpperInvariant(comparedTo);
        }

        int inputLen = input.Length;
        int comparedToLen = comparedTo.Length;

        int[,] matrix = new int[inputLen, comparedToLen];

        //initialize           
        for (var i = 0; i < inputLen; i++)
        {
            matrix[i, 0] = i;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < comparedToLen; i++)
        {
            matrix[0, i] = i;
        }

        //analyze
        for (var i = 1; i < inputLen; i++)
        {
            ushort si = input[i - 1];
            for (var j = 1; j < comparedToLen; j++)
            {
                ushort tj = comparedTo[j - 1];
                int cost = (si == tj) ? 0 : 1;

                int above = matrix[i - 1, j];
                int left = matrix[i, j - 1];
                int diag = matrix[i - 1, j - 1];
                int cell = FindMinimumOptimized(above + 1, left + 1, diag + cost);

                //transposition
                if (i > 1 && j > 1)
                {
                    int trans = matrix[i - 2, j - 2] + 1;
                    if (input[i - 2] != comparedTo[j - 1])
                    {
                        trans++;
                    }
                    if (input[i - 1] != comparedTo[j - 2])
                    {
                        trans++;
                    }
                    if (cell > trans)
                    {
                        cell = trans;
                    }
                }
                matrix[i, j] = cell;
            }
        }
        return matrix[inputLen - 1, comparedToLen - 1];
    }
```

Implemenation of Finding Minimum Optimized

```
public static int FindMinimumOptimized(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return Math.Min(a, Math.Min(b, c));
    }
```

Comment: You should never use MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10. Either you are CPU bound, and you will increase the threading overhead, or you are I/O bound and you should threadless I/O up your code.

Comment: You mean I shouldnt use the Parallel loop here or set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1?@Aron

Comment: new List<Tuple<long, string, string, string, string, string, double>>(); maybe you need a class

Comment: I mean asking each core to run 10 threads isn't going to make is go faster. I mean multi threading isn't free. It also looks like you are using a thread unsafe collection with threading.

Comment: `List` is not thread-safe. You can't `Add` to it the way you are doing.

Comment: @Shahid you need to use one of the thread safe collections from the [`System.Threading.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace. The nearest to a `List<T>` is  is probably `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Answer (score 2):

This is a computation that inherently has quadratic cost `O(N^2)`. This is always going to scale very badly as the number of items increases.

You can parallelize this but that's just a constant factor gain in the time it takes to execute.

Can you find some other criterion to match against that is based on equality? In that case you could use a hash based algorithm to very quickly create candidates for checking. For example, assuming that you are matching text articles and you expect almost all Levenstein matches to occur in articles written on the same calendar day, then you could match by date first (using O(N) complexity), and only then quadratically compare all items of that day. You could also compare items for the previous and next day to allow for some slack.

If you can't do that you have to accept quadratic scaling.

A good code pattern is this:

```
var pairs = (from a in listA
             from b in listB //cross product
             select new { a, b });

var matches = 
 pairs
 .AsParallel()
 .Where(pair => IsLevenshteinMatch(pair))
 .ToList();
```

You can throw out all of that complex code you have written for this. When working with concurrency or parallelism it often pays to ponder the best design a bit. Often, there are highly compact solutions for common problems.

Comment: Thanks @usr for your insightful answer. Unfortunately I don't have any other criterion to match. I try to find the best matched words from ListB which resemble ListA. I followed up on your suggestion and used the projection instead of nested for's but the performance gain has had no improvement.

Comment: @Shahid no, this has the same performance. You cannot do better given that you have to do quadratic matching. The choice of parallelization technique does not matter for performance because 99.999% of the time is spent in Levenshtein.

Comment: I had the same problem once. I matched long text articles. I was able to cut away many Levenshtein comparisons by first requiring that any two articles have a multiple rare words in common. This can use an equality based technique. I lost a few true Levenshein matches with that but the amount lost was very small. @Shahid Actually, I think I split the text into sentences and required that each article pair shared one fairly long sentence. I don't quite remember. You can get clever.

Comment: I stumbled upon this while looking to optimize the Levenshtein Algorithm https://github.com/felixfang/LevenshteinAutomaton Will have a look at it. Lets hope it provides a way out. Thanks for you help. Really appreciate!

Comment: @Shahid it seems you need to create an automaton for each different input. That would still be quadratic. Maybe it's still faster. I'd be interested in hearing about your results.

Comment: Thanks @usr. I will keep you posted.

Comment: This problem is still haunting me. I tried using  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fastenshtein/ a faster version nuget of Levenshtien it gave me a good performance benefit but when I talk about a match between millions of records its not sufficient.

Comment: I was wondering since I have both the data sets in database. Why don't I do it in SQL itself @usr What say?

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat if you push the logic into the database that saves you the data transfer to the application. But it does nothing to help the fundamental algorithm problem.; There are some useful text indexing algorithms that I read about. Text can be indexed to a hash. Similar texts convert to similar hashes. I think this is how Google finds duplicate content. It's called locality sensitive hashing. Maybe you can find something like that on the web.

Comment: I found something interesting this is what we are trying to solve here http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lxue/paper/sigmod09-entityextraction.pdf

Comment: I am having difficulties writing an implementation of this paper in C#. Can you guys help me with it. Thanks